# PWA authentication using Android account

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, progressive-web-apps, android-account

I have written SPA web app, where users logs in using AAD single-sign-on (open-id-connect), so that  request to backend's REST API are authenticated using a cookie header.

I would like to turn the app to PWA. Is it possible to use accounts registered in Android instead of having separate login experience? I mean the same account that Outlook or Teams apps uses.